# Why would be an attacker interested in whether a cryptographic key exchange protocol succeeded or not?

Tags: cryptography, key-exchange

Why would an attacker want to know if a key exchange between two parties succeeded or failed? What are some motivations for wanting to know this?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, and not a very well thought-out one either. I can't think off the top of my head a reason an attacker would want to know this, but there are many, many classes of attackers with many, many different motives.

Comment: It's not homework. If it's not a well thought-out one, then surely it's easy to answer?

Comment: As it is, it's just too broad. Can you narrow down your question a little bit? Right now the question could be put on hold for three different reasons: too broad, unclear what you're asking, and primarily opinion-based. Narrowing down your question a bit may make it answerable.

Comment: It wouldn't make any sense for me to narrow the question down -- for this is precisely what I am interested in. Could it be that it's not the question being too broad, but the moderators too narrow-minded? This question could hardly be any clearer, but I am happy to answer any further questions to help with the understanding. It seems to me that SE is somewhat dysfunctional because of this constant policing.

Comment: The issue is not that moderators are too narrow-minded. I personally have no idea how to answer this question. Do you just want someone to think up any contrived scenario where an attacker would care if key exchange between two parties succeeded or not?